# reduce function gives unexpected result in a 2d list in python

Tags: python, reduce

hi guys I wrote this small code , and in my understanding of the reduce function this code should give me the total of the the prices but it doesn't can any one explain what's going on.

```
import functools
bill = [["jaket" , 2500, 2] , ["ball" , 450 , 1] , ["calculator" , 120 , 4]]
lmbd_total = lambda data1 , data2 : data1[1]+data2[1]
totall = functools.reduce(lmbd_total , bill)
print(totall)
```

Comment: `lmbd_total = lambda acc , data2 : acc+data2[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> lmbd_total = lambda data1 , data2 : data1[1]+data2[1]

The first iteration will add correctly. But the second iteration, the accumulator `data1` is a `int` object and not a `list`. Therefore, `data1[1]` is not subscriptable. Add a `int` as `initializer` and make the accumulator constant type `int` .

```
bill = [["jaket" , 2500, 2] , ["ball" , 450 , 1] , ["calculator" , 120 , 4 ]]
lmbd_total = lambda acc , data2 : acc+data2[1]
totall = functools.reduce(lmbd_total , bill,0)
print(totall)
```

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` works like chaining, the result from the previous sum goes into the next invocation. So when you return an int from the first sum, it will be passed to the next call as `data1`. When it tries to do `data1[1]`, it will fail.

So you'll have to return something that "looks like" the data you are passing to `reduce`:

```
import functools

bill = [["jaket", 2500, 2], ["ball", 450, 1], ["calculator", 120, 4]]
lmbd_total = lambda data1, data2: (None, data1[1] + data2[1], None)
totall = functools.reduce(lmbd_total, bill)
print(totall[1])
```

Which is quite ugly-looking. You can get the same result with a simple `sum()`:

```
bill = [["jaket", 2500, 2], ["ball", 450, 1], ["calculator", 120, 4]]
totall = sum(a[1] for a in bill)
print(totall)
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that you got your answer, maybe it is also nice to know `accumulate` method from `itertools` which basically does the same this as `functools.reduce` as specified by [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster)'s concise and to the point answer. The only difference is that `accumualte` also returns intermediate values that could be suitable where you are working with data frames and would like to populate a new column based on other columns:

```
from itertools import accumulate

list(accumulate(bill, lambda x, y: x + y[1], initial = 0))

[0, 2500, 2950, 3070]
```